# How to deal with different jQuery versions?

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

For example
If you have a plugin on a site that uses jQuery 1.5.x and want to create a new plugin by implementing a script which uses an older version of jQuery, for example 1.3.x or 1.4.x.

I know it probably depends on jQuery functions that are called, but if you really had to use both 1.5 and some older version of jQuery.. how would you deal with this kind of situation? Is it even possible to use 2 different versions of jQuery at the same time without drawbacks?

Thanks.

Comment: [It is possible to load multiple versions of jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page), but you will need to adapt the code that uses it to reference the correct version. If you want this to work with the WordPress `wp_enqueue_script` functions, you will need to register two different scripts, like `jquery` and `jquery_13`. So in theory it is doable, but in practice it will be difficult (which is why I put this in a comment and not an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) in your new plugin.